# What is the right way of installing Drush?

Tags: 8, drush, composer

The http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install page states:

> Drush 9 only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal
>   8 site be [built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project).

and if you go to https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project and follow the given steps, in particular run the `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction` command, then:

1. You will have to create an empty directory (otherwise it will complain the given directory is not empty);
2. It will create Composer structure with Drupal 8 located in `web` sub-directory;
3. It will also create `vendor` sub-directory with lot's of other sub-directories as:

   alchemy       composer           doctrine         fabpot          league       phar-io        sebastian    theseer
   asm89         consolidation      drupal           grasmash        masterminds  phpdocumentor  squizlabs    twig
   autoload.php  container-interop  drupal-composer  guzzlehttp      mikey179     phpspec        stack        vlucas
   behat         cweagans           drush            instaclick      myclabs      phpunit        stecman      webflo
   bin           dflydev            easyrdf          jakub-onderka   nikic        psr            symfony      webmozart
   chi-teck      dnoegel            egulias          jcalderonzumba  paragonie    psy            symfony-cmf  zendframework

Now with regard the new way of isntalling Drupal 8 I have two questions:

1. Previously we would install Drupal 8 in document root set by control panel. Different control panel have different document roots, ours default them in `/home/username/public_html`.

Now, with the new way of installing Drupal 8 we end up with document root located in `/home/username/some-dir/web`, which does not play nice with our control panel's defaults. So I wonder what is the best recommended practice here?

Creating symbolic links between the old and new document roots also have its issues. For example, if you switch to `/home/username/public_html` (which is a symbolic link to `/home/username/some-dir/web`) and run the `composer update` command then it will give:

```
No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /home/username/some-dir? [Y,n]?
```

and we would really like to avoid this kind of extra steps, but at the same time respecting our control panel's default settings.

Changing the default setting for document roots in control panel is also not a good option as there could be lot's of old and non-Drupal websites on servers, so the old document root must be kept.

2. Do we have to have Composer structure with lot's of sub-directories like ones in `vendor` in every website's home directory? Please note that in my test setup Composer is installed globally. But when you run the `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction` command it creates all those directories within a website's home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to run `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction` to create a new Drupal 8 site using the `drupal-project` composer package.

You can also just download the `composer.json` of that project and place it into your future Drupal 8 base folder. Then you can alter the installer paths within that `composer.json` to your liking. So if you prefer `public` over `web` as your Drupal root, then rename that part of the installer paths. You may also wish to alter the project name or other details of the `composer.json` file.

After your customization, you can then run `composer update` to generate an according `composer.lock` file. Assuming you did so on a local development environment, you can then use `composer install --no-dev` on your production system after uploading your composer and custom files/checking them out if you use a code versioning system.

Coming to the folder structure: It is advisable to keep the folder above the Drupal 8 root as base folder of your root package (project), location for the composer dependencies (`vendor` folder), Drush site settings, and auxillary files that should not be directly accessible from your web URLs (e.g. exported configuration files, private files, temporary files, Node.js packages, ...).

Therefore you should consider pointing your virtual hosts' root directories for example to `/home/username/public_html/web` (or `/home/username/public_html/public`, if you customized your `composer.json` like that) while using the regular root directories of your hosting panel `/home/username/public_html` as composer root package folder.

Depending on your hosting panel, you may have the ability to alter the vhost root directory by overriding the web server settings (e.g. defining a `DocumentRoot` for Apache, or a `root` for Nginx). How to do this depends heavily on your used hosting solution and is therefore off-topic in Drupal Answers.

And yes, you will have this folder structure on every of your projects. As every project may require a different version of dependencies, different modules (which may add dependencies with certain version restrictions to the vendor folder as well), binary tools for the shell, probably applied patches and so on. These dependencies and their version requirements are project specific, even when you use a global Composer installation.

Comment: Mario, thanks for the detailed explanation. Before accepting your answer, mind elaborating little further? As sated in 1) running Composer in /home/username/public_html, it complains the directory is not empty. And that directory unfortunately can not be empty, because the control panel places bunch of own files and directories in it. Thus the problem. So would you advice create Composer in empty directory first and then move the whole structure back to `/home/username/public_html` to mix everything up? Changing document root and Apache configuration is not an option for.

Comment: As stated within my answer: Use Composer *within* `public_html`, not one folder above. Empty it, if required. This leaves you with a Drupal root in a subfolder of `public_html`. Then alter your vhost document root to point to that subfolder. I'm pretty sure you can do so, as all (good) hosting solutions allow for additional server directives. Benefit of this solution: `public_html` may have been added to the PHP open_basedir already by the hosting solution. So you don't need additional settings to access private files outside your Drupal root.

Comment: I know I could alter doc root, but I really wanted to keep one standard document root for all types of other websites and CMS like WordPress across the server, because the control panel has bunch of automated scripts bound to that kind of default structure. Is there any other way of not changing document root?

Comment: According to your folder structure description: I doubt it. Maybe you're able to create a dedicated vhost template for Drupal 8/Magento 2/... that all use a similar project structure and built-in composer dependencies. Or you will end up mixing project code with server stats and so on, which makes it pretty unhandy for using code versioning or automatic deployments. But that really is off-topic in Drupal Answers...

Comment: Fair enough. I accepted your answer as it provided more details. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that Drupal core has a .htaccess/web.config rule to deny web access to the vendor directory, so it's not really a risk to have it in there, although if you're using a web server that doesn't use either of those you will need to sort out your own access rules. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Composer%21Composer.php/function/Composer%3A%3AensureHtaccess/

Answer (score 0):

> with the new way of installing Drupal 8 we end up with document
>   root located in /home/username/some-dir/web, which does not play nice
>   with our control panel's defaults. So I wonder what is the best
>   recommended practice here?

Navigate to the directory, then run the composer command. Composer will install Drupal at the directory from which you run the command.

> Do we have to have Composer structure with lot's of sub-directories
>   like ones in vendor in every website's home directory?

Each Drupal 8  (and likely 9+) will have its own /vendor directory.

Comment: When I run Composer in /home/username/public_html, it complains the directory is not empty. And that directory unfortunately can not be empty, because the control panel places bunch of own files and directories in it. Thus the problem.

Comment: Delete all those files. You don’t need them.

Comment: Believe me I do. Those are: `awstats  cgi-bin  domains  etc  fcgi-bin  logs  mailboxes  Maildir  private  public_html  tmp  www`.

Comment: And sorry for confusion, I tried to run Composer command in `/home/username` and not in `/home/username/public_html` as previously stated, because `/home/username/public_html` is the root where Drupal 8 should reside, however one level up there are bunch of NEEDED files and directories.