# How can I use Drush in a project installed with Composer?

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I have installed Drupal 8.5 using `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --stability dev --no-interaction`.

This command installs many files. I found drush-files in the root and the file vendor/drush.
It looks like Drush is available, but I have no idea how I can run drush. Trying command like "drush cr" was not successful. I get the following error.

> -bash: drush: command not found.

I don't want to be able to use Drush from everywhere.

How can I use Drush only from my_site_name_dir?

Comment: Did you try `cd`ing into the `docroot` (or web) folder and running `../vendor/bin/drush` ? If that works, whats missing is an alias. I am not familiar with Drupal-Composer but some scaffolders like Acquia BLT do that part for you automagically. Did you also try restarting terminal?

Comment: @Kevin Yes I have tried with no success. But the alias was a good reference. I make one in my .bash_profile. And now it works for me.

Comment: That's what [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) is for. A global `drush` command to always pick up a Composer-based project's local Drush. See https://www.drush.org/install/

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you need to follow steps on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install and get Drush installed globally. It's possible to invoke Drush installed within Composer context together with Drupal 8 indicating the exact path something like `/path-to-website-home/vendor/bin/drush`. However, if you want Drush available anywhere in the system then get Drush Launcher installed.

Here is direct quote from http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install:

> Optional. To be able to call drush from anywhere, install the Drush
>   Launcher. That is a small program which listens on your $PATH and
>   hands control to a site-local Drush that is in the /vendor directory
>   of your Composer project. If you skip this step, run Drush from Drupal
>   root via ../vendor/bin/drush. In that case Drush's bash integration
>   and custom prompt won't work.

You might also want to read [How to get Drush to work with Composer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258464/how-to-get-drush-to-work-with-composer) and [What is the right way of installing Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258329/what-is-the-right-way-of-installing-drupal-8)

Comment: I thought this was no longer advised and instead you should use Drush 9 and install it as a project dependency?

Comment: Drush 9 will work only with Drupal 8, but there could be Drupal 7 or 6 websites on the same server, so when you say `I don't want to be able to use Drush from everywhere` that means Drush work with all versions of Drupal and that's where Drush Launcher comes in to play as it automatically detects Drupal version of the current working directory and loads necessary Drush version environment.

Comment: Drush docs moved to https://www.drush.org/install/

Answer (score 3):

I got it by myself. There is no need to install drush globally. The composer command
    composer require drush/drush
install all the necessary files for using drush.
To make Drush run you need an alias to this file in your .bash_profile (mac users). I only add in the .bash_profile
    alias drush='vendor/drush/drush/drush'
And Drush works!
And there is also no need to have trouble with different drupal versions, because composer install the version you need.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 so I had to edit my ~./bashrc file and add a line at the end with `alias drush='vendor/drush/drush/drush'`

Comment: @bwaindwain that should actually be ~/.bashrc and is not just valid in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition for windows users.

lesley n. answer above works just fine for Windows users as well.

Just edit `C:\Users\your_username\.bash_profile` and add one line:

```
alias drush='vendor/bin/drush'
```

Restart your Git Bash, go to your drupal site home folder and try:

```
drush version
```

It should work

I was able to make composer-installed Drupal Console to work with only "drupal" command also with one line addition to `C:\Users\your_username\.bash_profile` as well:

```
alias drupal='vendor/bin/drupal'
```

Restart your Git Bash, go to your drupal site home folder and try:

```
drupal --version
```

This should work as well.

These two solutions are much easier for me than installing Drush Launcher and Console Launcher on my Windows platform.

Please, note that due to the relative alias paths this only works when you call `drush` and `drupal` commands from inside your project root.

Comment: That's what [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) is for. A global `drush` command to always pick up a Composer-based project's local Drush.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for your concerns. I didn't install global Drush. I know that it is not supported any more. I have Drush installed with Composer as dependency for each of my project. And the above method works nice. If it works nice for everybody I see both Drush launcher and Console launcher as unneeded tools any more. Did you try the above method or are you posting recommendation for Drush launcher without trying above method? It is an important detail for others who read this discussion to know.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are referencing an relative path. It's actually quite clever, but the problem is this only works when you call `drush` from inside the project root. Maybe add that little bit of info.

Comment: Thnx @leymannx. I have added a note to the bottom of my post. BTW... why is it a problem? I have never used `drush` or `drupal` command outside of my project root anyway. Is there any reason why we need to use `drush` command outside of our project root sometimes? And, if yes... is this reason still valid now when global Drush installation is no more supported?

Comment: Of course this reason is valid, that's one of the reasons Drush Launcher exists. Imagine during development you `cd web/themes/custom/MYTHEME && gulp build` and then want to `drush cr` immediately thereafter. With Drush Launcher and a fallback Drush you can even run `drush` from outside a project again by passing the `--root` option to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.

That  means after you added Drush via `composer require drush/drush` to your project you then call Drush via `vendor/bin/drush cr` or `vendor/drush/drush/drush cr` from inside the project root.

If you are working on many Drupal (7, 8 and 8+) projects or if you are simply preferring to call a global `drush` command like you are used to you can install the [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) and then only have to type `drush cr` again from anywhere inside the project. The Drush Launcher simply picks up the local Drush in each project. Which is especially nice when you have projects requiring different versions of Drush.

See the [new docs](https://www.drush.org/install/) for more info and for a [Drupal Compatibility](https://www.drush.org/install/#drupal-compatibility) chart.